# Indexing two similar tables in two different databases: got speed boost on one, and nothing on another

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two databases - `db1` and `db2` with almost similar construction. One of them has a table `users` with 40,000 records, another one also has a table `users` with 50,000 entries.

Both of these tables have a key `user` that I decided to index by, so as `select foo where user = bar` statements would take no time.

I've successfully did it on the `db1`, thus reducing the time of the mentioned select statement from 0.03 to about 0.001.

But, I was really surprised to find that indexing the similar table in `db2` changed nothing in speed. Just, nothing at all. The select statement takes the same 0.03 sec as it did. I've tried to remove index and add it again, and nothing changed.

Worth noticing, that I used exactly the same sentence to create index:

```
create index user on users(user);
```

Both databases reside on the same server.

I have tried restarting the mysql server.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, I've solved this problem really fast after I asked this question.

The problem was - in the database where index had no effect, the column `user` type was `varchar`.

So, I've modified it to be `bigint` like in the first database - and immediately got the same performance boost as in the first table.

Worth to notice, that the column actually contained nothing but numbers with the length up to 9. Not exactly sure why indexing varchar column had no effect, but at least there's a workaround now.

I'm leaving it here, maybe someone runs into the similar problem.

Comment: In case of varchar index scan look for whole string search do left-oriented LIKE searches. While in case of integer/bigint it look a range of numbers which reduce the traversing time and this reflect in performance of the query.

Comment: Put differently, ...  `WHERE varchar_col = 1234` cannot use an index.  Any other combination (varchar:string; int:number; int:string) can.